# How do I publish an event stream which has schema same as Input stream

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I need to process an input stream an publish the processed stream which has same schema as input stream to the logger.

In other words I need to have the same schema for import and export definitions. How do I solve this issue?

Is this possible to do in wso2 cep using siddhi QL?

Answer (score 0):

Even If both the input and output streams have the same schema still you are required to have two streams with the same schema.

If you use the same stream as input and output stream it will make the CEP engine to stuck in an infinite loop because output of the query becomes an input subsequently if you use the same stream for both input and output.

Comment: having two streams with same schema is possible? how does an input event decide which schema it belongs to?

Comment: It's possible to have two stream with the same schema. When you publish data into a stream you have to specify to which stream you are publishing to. Are you using WSO2 CEP server for this?

Comment: yes I am  using wso2 cep server. I will try it out as you have mentioned